# asp.net values of Session variables in Session_End event

Tags: asp.net, events, session, session-variables

If I store a value in a session variable

```
    Session["Int"] = 100;
```

What it will be in the Session_End event? Will it be null or 100?

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      object objInt = Session["Int"];          // Null or 100 ?
}
```

Meaning, will Session_End fire after disposing everything in the session or just before?

Comment: Why don't you put a breakpoint on that method and see what is the value when the breakpoint is hit?

Comment: also check this for HttpContext.Current http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030113/asp-net-session-variables-on-session-end

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is 100.

To test it yourself simply add the ASP.NET application file [`global.asax`](http://aspalliance.com/1114_Understanding_the_Globalasax_file.all) to your project and handle the `Session_Start` end [`Session-End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx) events:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session["Int"] = 100;          // 100
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object objInt = Session["Int"];  // it is still 100 here
}
```

You can end a Session by [`Session.Abandon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx) (or when it expires).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();  // after this Session.End is called
}
```

Comment: also check this for HttpContext.Current http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030113/asp-net-session-variables-on-session-end

Answer (score 0):

I found that Session["Int"] will be 100. I set the session timeout to just 1 minute and put a break point in that event.

Comment: well when i posted my answer somebody has already answered it so it was a coincident